# How to retrieve Ruby/Sinatra params from array of params?

Tags: ruby, hashmap, parameters

My ExtJS frontend sends such a param hash to my Sinatra backend:

```
{"_dc"=>"1365959782607", "page"=>"6", "start"=>"250", "limit"=>"50", "sort"=>"[{\"property\":\"port\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"}]"}
```

How to get the params 'property' and 'direction'?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the following way:

```
require 'json'
a = {"_dc"=>"1365959782607", "page"=>"6", "start"=>"250", "limit"=>"50", "sort"=>"[{\"property\":\"port\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"}]"}

sort = JSON.parse a["sort"]
p sort[0]["property"] # "port"
p sort[0]["direction"]  # "ASC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do Sinatra, it's a basic question of how to extract values from a hash and deal with JSON:

```
require 'json'
hash = {"_dc"=>"1365959782607", "page"=>"6", "start"=>"250", "limit"=>"50", "sort"=>"[{\"property\":\"port\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"}]"}

JSON[hash['sort']].first.values_at('property', 'direction')
=> ["port", "ASC"]
```

Parsing the serialized object using `JSON[hash['sort']]` returns an array containing a single hash. `first` will return that hash. At that point it's just the usual methods to get at the values. I used `values_at` to return them as an array.

Pass `JSON[]` a string and JSON will try to parse it, expecting a JSON encoded object. Pass `JSON[]` another object, like an array or hash, and JSON will encode it into its serialized format.